# java.lang.Float to Oracle DB number(3,3)

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee

I have a float value in Java, to update into a Oracle 10g Database. The column's data type is number(3,3). But when I try to insert it shows:

> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

How to downcast the float to store into the Database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

number(3, 3) means precision (max digits) = 3 and scale (digits after decimal point) = 3  that is you can store only values < 1.0 in such column, try it

Comment: What is the logic behind this? How to find out ranges like this?

Comment: All logic is here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i22289 it's not about JDBC